# Android AppCompatCheckbox padding/margin/gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I have a AppCompatCheckBox in my layout. This is how it looks like:

[image]

The problem is the padding or margin or gravity is not the way I want it to be. There is a small gap between the Box and the left border. I set gravity to left/start paddding and margin to 0 but the gap still exists. How can I remove this? I want it to be completely at the left border or centered. Both would be okay. But set gravity to center does not work, too.

Anyone has an idea?

The CheckBox and the Text should be above each other.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRoot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCbs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="?attr/textColor" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="?attr/textColor" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="?attr/textColor" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide you layout XML, this will help us helping you.

Comment: It's most likely intrinsic padding in the drawable; i.e., blank space between the box and the edge of the image. You might be able to use a negative left/start padding on the `View`, but that's really hacky. Probably the best way to handle it is to provide your own drawable.

Comment: Post your *xml* code.

Comment: Added XML-Code. @RaymonddelaCroix

Comment: Added XML-Code. @jaydroider

Comment: @L3n95 How you have setup the black border to the *AppCompatCheckBox* ?

Comment: @jaydroider is default. I have not changed anything. I have style: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" maybe it gets the color fom this style?

Comment: @L3n95 Not sure may be it should have been taking it from default style of *AppCompatCheckBox*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not a problem of the AppCompatCheckBox but of the CheckBox itself. The only solution I found is to set negative margin (for me -7dp was great).

Answer (score 3):

Set Checkbox `minWidth` and `minHeight` value to Zero

```
checkbox.setMinWidth(0);
checkbox.setMinHeight(0);
```

or via xml

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your AppCompatCheckbox at center simply by adding linearlayout and set its gravity to center and add the AppCompatCheckbox  as its child.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: strange!!  @L3n95 it should work for setting the checkbox in the center. it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the container layout does not have a margin applied to it

check this out **http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/**